# In CommaIDE, what is the difference between running a cro service as a regular script and running it as a cro service?

Tags: raku, cro, commaide

I have run some cro microservices from CommaIDE (Community version 2020.05) without a glitch, before discovering I could also sun them as a cro service itself. However, there does not seem to be any visible difference; configuration screens are the same, and running them seems to have the same effect, being able to stop them from the IDE and so on. Is there something here I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At present, the only significant difference is that the Cro Service run configuration sets up environment variables based on the `.cro.yml` specification of the service, so you need not do that step by yourself.

Future developments will likely bring further differences, however. For example, display and navigation of Cro pipeline traces within the IDE is planned, and will probably be enabled through an option in this run configuration.